# Text file comes back empty when loading with Ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, text-files

I've searched and searched and could not find a solution for this:
I'm trying to load .txt file contents with Ajax but the file comes back empty.
I checked the ready state and status. ready state is 4 which means that connection was set, data received , status is 0 which means error for loading http but I read on a forum that it is ok for a local file.
I really don't know what to do.
all help will be appreciated!
this is my code:

```
<script>    
    function load() {
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        var xhttp;

        alert("in func")

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            try{
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e){

                }
            }
        }

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && (xhttp.status == 200 || xhttp.status == 0)) {
                document.getElementById("textDiv").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                alert(xhttp.responseText);
            }
        };

        if(selectedValue == "Year 1"){
             xhttp.open("GET", "file://year1.txt", true);
             xhttp.send(null);
        }

        if(selectedValue == "Year 2"){
            xhttp.open("GET", "year2.txt", true);
            xhttp.send(null);
        }

        if(selectedValue == "Year 3"){
            xhttp.open("GET", "year3.txt", true);
            xhttp.send(null);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely the file protocol: `file://year1.txt`

try using a relative path instead, ie `./year1.txt`

**Edit..**

I missed this the first time around.. you will get several hits to your callback function on a successful call. You'll get one where the status is zero first, then if successful you'll get another one with a 200. Why are you checking for both?

change this...

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && (xhttp.status==200 || xhttp.status==0))
```

to this...

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status==200)
```

Comment: should there be any special headers or text in the txt file? What am I missing?

Comment: tried that too :) The thing is it always returns status 0 and I found somewhere that it's ok for a .txt file (though can't be sure if it is correct) .but if it is not than - the status is 0. and I haven't found a solution .

Comment: well, then I'm out of ideas. what does it say in your console? looked at firebug? what's in the response tab?

Comment: *also firebug does not work with local pages, I'd have to load them into a local server which is probably not what was asked in my assignment...

Comment: @AlexK are you running the javascript from the file protocol too? That definitely wont work it's considered a cross site request.

Comment: Yes! I after using devtools this is exactly the error it gave me:Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.....any idea what to do with it? Thank you!

Comment: Html and Javascript files can be viewed without the file protocol. Just remove the file part from the browser and add the http part.

Comment: when I tried removing the file:// part and adding the http:// it did not find the file.

Comment: also , I think the problem is with the txt file that I'm trying to load.I found solutions that say that you have to allow file access in chrome but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

OK! after EXTENSIVE research the problem was the infamous cross origin request problem (which does not allow access to local files as part of a security measure to insure you don't upload infected files &ct)
the solution is :

when initializing the variable for the XMLHttpRequest write:

```
 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
```

(notice the {mozSystem: true} inside the request)

AND IT SOLVES THE PROBLEM!!!
Thank you for your time, I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer worked but not for long - after I restarted my computer the ajax stopped working at started throwing the cross origin error again. so- the best option I found that also works for all the browsers I checked (chrome, IE), is to set up a local server and run it from there.

here is a link  for instructions:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-web-server-all-platforms/

Good luck!